# Spring cloud java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to run a Spring Cloud Config application where I am getting the error.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.demo'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}


ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

Below is the application.yml file which is present in the resources folder.
application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8085

spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/[DEMO]/TProj
```

`https://github.com/[DEMO]/TProj` contains `application.yml` file

I  am getting the below error Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load environment

Error:

```
2018-06-03 15:15:51.450  INFO 8392 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-06-03 15:15:51.451  INFO 8392 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-06-03 15:15:51.490  INFO 8392 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 39 ms
2018-06-03 15:15:52.390 ERROR 8392 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load environment] with root cause

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.HttpClientConfigurableHttpConnectionFactory.lookupHttpClientBuilder(HttpClientConfigurableHttpConnectionFactory.java:69) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.HttpClientConfigurableHttpConnectionFactory.create(HttpClientConfigurableHttpConnectionFactory.java:56) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.httpOpen(TransportHttp.java:830) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-4.11.0.201803080745-r.jar:4.11.0.201803080745-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:491) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-4.11.0.201803080745-r.jar:4.11.0.201803080745-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:345) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-4.11.0.201803080745-r.jar:4.11.0.201803080745-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:137) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-4.11.0.201803080745-r.jar:4.11.0.201803080745-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:123) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-4.11.0.201803080745-r.jar:4.11.0.201803080745-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1269) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-4.11.0.201803080745-r.jar:4.11.0.201803080745-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:241) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-4.11.0.201803080745-r.jar:4.11.0.201803080745-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:306) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-4.11.0.201803080745-r.jar:4.11.0.201803080745-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:200) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-4.11.0.201803080745-r.jar:4.11.0.201803080745-r]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.cloneToBasedir(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:560) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.copyRepository(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:535) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.createGitClient(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:518) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.refresh(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:259) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.getLocations(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:238) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.getLocations(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:150) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.findOne(AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.java:47) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.findOne(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:190) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.CompositeEnvironmentRepository.findOne(CompositeEnvironmentRepository.java:46) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentEncryptorEnvironmentRepository.findOne(EnvironmentEncryptorEnvironmentRepository.java:53) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.labelled(EnvironmentController.java:122) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.defaultLabel(EnvironmentController.java:106) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:84) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

What can be the cause of the issue? How can I solve this problem? Is this some network or proxy issue?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1028

Comment: Yes, When I am running the same above code in my Linux system, it is working fine, but the same code is not working on Windows and giving the above error.

Comment: Keep an eye on that thread, it’s work in progress, should  be rectified in next release they make.

Comment: @IndraneelBende, Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by adding "spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri" property in my application.properties file.
Although I am using Maven instead of Gradle.

We need to add below to the application.properties file of the config server:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///C:/folder-to-your-local-gitconfig-repo-where-the-property-file-has-been-saved
```

Also, make sure that that the path to the file does not have any spaces.

Hope this might help.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I have faced the similar problem and resolved the issue by changing the SpringBoot version to 1.5.13.RELEASE.

But with SpringBoot version 2.0.2.RELEASE, I'm still facing the same issue. Looks the bug is closed now, but not sure what changes I need to do in code to fix the issue? Anyone has any idea?

**Resolution:**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.13.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting config-server takes some time due to fetching remote git server. When micro services are running at the same time, config-clients will probably open before config-server. This will cause the similar errors.

**SOLUTION 1**:
To solution can be added to wait scripts into docker images like below
https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.7.3/wait

But this solution has some disadvantages. When code changed, docker only restarts modified docker image. In this case previous docker image cannot be deleted from name server(such as Eureka) due to kill signal goes to bash script.

**SOLUTION 2**:
Simple solution just can be added two dependencies to config-clients to be able to retry

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I think this is better solution. Because when service goes down name server can be set it down immediately